# firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

How can i solve this firebase error ? I had used stripe extension in firebase and when i'm going to save the data in firebase it shows me the error "firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default function"

Here is my code **"db.js"** :

```
  const checkout_sessionsRef =await firestore
.collection('user')
.doc(uid)
.collection('checkout_sessions')
.add({
    price : 'price_1IGEdTKDPaWWeL1ymwWH5Ubb',
    success_url :window.location.origin,
    cancel_url:window.location.origin,
});
```

Comment: Can you share the whole, exact error, along with the stack trace?

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.collection is not a function